# Plotting points on a bell curve in D3

Tags: d3.js, statistics

I can't figure out for the life of me why my points aren't drawing. The only thing I can think of is that my scale is off in some fashion, but if that's the case, I'm not sure how, as the numbers look right. Help!

Here's the plunker.. http://plnkr.co/edit/U48zrI

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

svg.append('points').selectAll('circle')
    .data(plotPoints)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {console.log(d.score); return x(d.score);})
    .attr('cy', function (d) {console.log(y(0.002)); return y(0.002);})
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('class','red');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no  SVG Elements, change point to g:

```
svg.append('g').selectAll('circle') 
    .data(plotPoints)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {console.log(d.score); return x(d.score);})
    .attr('cy', function (d) {console.log(y(0.002)); return y(0.002);})
    .attr('r', 3)
    .attr('class','red');
```